# How to find DateDiff from same column with condition in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am having one table in PowerBI which is having 3 columns: 1.EnrollId 2.Status 3.StatusChangeDate. One EnrollId is having 4 statuses and their particular statusChangeDates. I want to find no. of days between two dates with status condition.

```
EnrollId   Status         StatusChangeDate
101        AppStart       15/02/2019
101        Application    27/03/2019
101        Enrollment     03/04/2019
101        Complete       28/04/2019
```

I want to create formula in DAX like

```
[StatusChangeDate (where Status="Enrollment") - StatusChangeDate(where status="AppStart)]
```

or

```
[StatusChangeDate (where Status="Complete")- StatusChangeDate(where status="Enrollment)]
```

---

```
i.e.  03/04/2019 - 15/02/2019 = 44 Days
      28/04/2019 - 03/04/2019 = 25 Days
```

Comment: Are you looking for a calculated column or a measure? Can you show us what the result you want would look like?

Comment: @Macro Vos I want measure that should return number of days between two dates. I want use that measure to show number of days required for particular status change on visual.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is go for a Calculated Column, you can try and adjust this to a measure but there is more factors to consider regarding the filter context.

For a calculated column:

```
DaysLastChange = 
VAR _currentStatusChangeDate = [StatusChangeDate]
VAR _currentEnrollId = [EnrollId]
RETURN
    DATEDIFF(
        CALCULATE(MAX('Table1'[StatusChangeDate]);FILTER('Table1';_currentEnrollId = [EnrollId] && _currentStatusChangeDate > [StatusChangeDate] ));
        _currentStatusChangeDate;
        DAY
    )
```

[image: outcome]

Answer (score 0):

If you want measures, try something like this. For each period between two Statuses, you need to create another measure. When more than one [EnrollId] is selected, the measure returns a blank.

```
Days Enrollment - Complete =
VAR scDateEnrollment =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[StatusChangeDate] ), 'Table'[Status] = "Enrollment" )
VAR scDateComplete =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[StatusChangeDate] ), 'Table'[Status] = "Complete" )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Table'[EnrollId] ),
        DATEDIFF ( scDateEnrollment, scDateComplete, DAY )
    )
```

Cardvisuals or a table-visual would look like this. As you can see the table-visual is not affected by the slicer.

[image]

**EDIT**
This is the table i used:

[image]

Comment: @Macro Vos What can I do for multiple EnrollIds?

Comment: What do you mean? In my answer i used a table with multiple EnrollId's. See Edit.

Comment: Actually I want to show average days required for status change per year for multiple EnrollIds. That means according to you edited table's data, I have to show Avg days AppStarted - Enrollment = (47 + 59)/2 = 53 and Avg Days Enrollment - Complete =  (25 + 19)/2 = 22. Your table is showing for each EnrollId. And I have to use that with Line and stacked column chart with X-axis value as Year. Visuals will be different for each status change.